# Define custon named route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I define routes, to get the following result:

```
 new_ad GET    /ads/new/:type(.:format)        ads#new
    ads POST   /ads(.:format)                  ads#create
edit_ad GET    /ads/:id/edit(.:format)         ads#edit
     ad GET    /ads/:id(.:format)              ads#show
        PUT    /ads/:id(.:format)              ads#update
        DELETE /ads/:id(.:format)              ads#destroy
```

In general, I need to specify type param in new path and to be able to user path helpers like this:

```
new_ad_path("somytype") # -> ads/new/somytype -> ads#new -> params[:type] = "somytype"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your routes.rb

`get '/ads/new/:type' => 'ads#new', as: :new_ad`

@mind.blank's solution will also work fine

Answer (score 1):

To pass in a param you would do the following:

```
new_ad_path(type: "sometype")
```

This would result in:

```
/ads/new?type=sometype
```

Then in the controller you can check the param type and do whatever is needed with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can define those routes with:

```
resources :ads, except: [:index, :new] do
  get '/ads/new/:type', on: :collection, as: :new_ad
end
```